# Invalid eclipse home when installing Eclim

Tags: java, eclipse, vim

I am encountering a issue when installing the `Eclim`. It is not able to detect the location of the Eclipse. At the installation screen, I select the Eclipse home folder, but the `Eclim` installer has an error with the message:

```
Invalid eclipse home (no 'plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar' found)
```

I have installed my Eclipse using the [new Eclipse installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php?show_instructions=TRUE). And my `Eclim` is version 2.5.0, downloaded from [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/eclim/eclim/2.5.0/eclim_2.5.0.jar?r=http%3A%2F%2Feclim.org%2Finstall.html&ts=1443107533&use_mirror=nchc).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ervandew/eclim/issues/436) this is a known issue.

It looks like the easiest solution is to download the .tar.gz version you need from here: https://eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In the new eclipse installer click the top right icon for settings and uncheck the bundle pool checkbox. It should work.